# Get value of relation of pivot table laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Model **ListDeals**

```
class ListsDeals extends Model
{
protected $table = "deals";

protected $fillable = ['title', 'slug', 'description', 'price', 'has_discount', 'price_to_discount', 'price_reduced', 'status', 'approved', 'suspended', 'start_date', 'end_date'];

public function lists()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Lists', 'list_has_deals' , 'deal_id', 'list_id')->withPivot('list_id');
}

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}
```

Model **Lists**

```
class Lists extends Model
{

protected $table = "lists";

protected $fillable = ['title', 'slug', 'short_description', 'description', 'website', 'email', 'phone', 'lat_map', 'lng_map', 'address_reference', 'video', 'renewal_date', 'status', 'approved', 'suspended'];

public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\ListsCategories', 'list_has_categories' , 'list_id', 'category_id');
}

public function deals()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\ListsDeals', 'list_has_deals' , 'list_id', 'deal_id');
}

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}
```

Pivot Table **list_has_deals**

```
id
list_id
deal_id
```

Controller **HomePageController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Lists;
use App\Models\ListsCategories;
use App\Models\ListsDeals;
use DB;

class HomePageController extends Controller
{

public function homepage(){

    $matchThese = [ 'suspended' => 0, 'status' => 1, 'approved' => 1 ];

    $deals = ListsDeals::where( $matchThese )->limit( 3 )->offset( 0 )->orderBy( 'start_date' )->get();

    return view( "homepage" )
            ->with( "deals", $deals );

}

}
```

I want get in the view the same categories of the list for the deal in the HomePageController, but i dont kwno thw way, i try with withPivot('list_id') but i dont get the id of the list, thank for the help.

Comment: Please don't just dump all your code. You should include a [minimal, viable, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I already included the relevant code for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the section **Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns**

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Yes, i already check that but the example is this

$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    echo $role->pivot->created_at;
}

that find the user with a manual number, i want find with the list_id in the table